# Custom validation "e-mail OR phone required" in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I need custom validation for two fields that is Email and Phone, but at least one field is required.

Users must enter email or phone. so how to merge both fields for validation? also I'm confused about how to return an error in case our validation is failed.

If solution can be specific for a single form (via ID) that would be great.

Comment: You can use a Contact form 7 filter validation. https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

Comment: yes I've seen this but method "wpcf7_validate_email" is specific for email i guess...

Comment: No, that's wrong. You can set wpcf7_validate_* (* = your input name) and applicate your php rules in filter function

Comment: Sorry for necrothreading but: I'm an expert developer but I never worked with WP before (and hope to have not in the future). The documentation posted by @Stefano Pascazi is clear and easy but it doesn't tell where (which file) I have to edit or create to add my validation function. Thanks.